Why is the WireGuard handshake changing destination and source IP after eth0 enabled?
Whenever I plug in an Ethernet cable into eth0 it seems to modify the source and destination of WireGuard packets being replied. In this situation the WireGuard interface is unable to function.
My setup is a Raspberry Pi 5. The Raspberry Pi 5 is connected to the internet via wlan0. All outbound traffic that isn't coming from the local network are sent out over a VPN interface wg1. This is functioning correctly. I have the WireGuard packets marked with 0x15 on the way in so that they are routed back out over wlan0 back to the source.

wlan0 IP: 192.168.5.160
eth0 IP: 192.168.6.1

Below is normal behavior when I make a wg0 connection from outside:
pi5 kernel: Inbound Connection:  IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=<WANIP> DST=192.168.5.160 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=48888 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44311 DPT=51820 LEN=156 MARK=0x15
pi5 kernel: Outbound Connection:  IN= OUT=lo SRC=192.168.5.160 DST=WANIP LEN=120 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x80 TTL=64 ID=2721 PROTO=UDP SPT=51820 DPT=44311 LEN=100 MARK=0x15

Now below is what happens after I plug in eth0:
pi5 kernel: Inbound Connection:  IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC= SRC=WANIP DST=192.168.5.160 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=56930 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=60019 DPT=51820 LEN=156 MARK=0x15
pi5 kernel: Outbound Connection:  IN= OUT=lo SRC=192.168.6.1 DST=192.168.5.160 LEN=120 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x80 TTL=64 ID=7723 PROTO=UDP SPT=51820 DPT=60019 LEN=100

The reply packet appears to use the source IP from the eth0 interface and the destination is set to the wlan0 interface. Also the mark is lost. If I pull out the eth0 cable it goes back to functioning like above. I'm a bit lost. The default route is not modified when the eth0 cable is plugged in.
Any ideas where I should look?

I resolved it but I don't understand why this worked.
I added:
ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 51820 lookup 100
I also had to remove a SNAT rule that I had on the incoming packets
iptables -t nat -D INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.5.160
I already had other rules/routes:
ip route add default via 192.168.5.1 table 100
ip rule add fwmark 0x15 table 100
My previous setup was about marking packets as they came in on wlan0 and restoring the mark for related packets. These packets would be captured by the fwmark rule and get their own route.
